# Changing the close tab keycombo for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

Right now, the close tab button is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Does anyone know of any way to change this? And does anyone know of a possible consequence of changing it?

**FYI**: I want to change it because the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is fidgity on my keyboard. Closing the tab via keyboard is something that I do often so wanted to see if I could perhaps change the hotkey to just <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> also works.

Comment: Not helpful, @muntoo. His issue is with the `Ctrl` key.

Comment: @Randolph Woops, I thought it was the `F4` key, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctrl-w` will also close tabs, but that doesn't really solve your `ctrl` issue. So there are extensions which can help.

- [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) is pretty straightforward from what I can gather, but there appear to be issues running on Chrome 10.
- [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) is my preferred method of browsing the web. But the keybindings may be unfamiliar if you've not used vim. The default kebindings work `x` closes the current tab, `X` reopens. The most recent versions overrides `ctrl-f` and `ctrl-d` but that is easy to revert. Additionally you can add any custom bindings you desire.

Comment: Vimium is awesome! I'm digging it.